# How to set selected item in MvxSpinner

Tags: android, spinner, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an MvxSpinner that is bound to a `List<PhotoCategory>` thus:

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    style="@style/Spinners"
    android:id="@+id/photoCategorySpinner"
    android:prompt="@string/photoCategory_prompt"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PhotoCategories; SelectedItem SelectedPhotoCategory; Visibility ShowPhotoFields, Converter=Visibility"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_photocategories"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_photocategory" />
```

The `SelectedPhotoCategory` that the SelectedItem is bound to is also a `PhotoCategory`. When this screen is in "update mode", the ViewModel sets the `SelectedPhotoCategory` to the PhotoCategory whose PhotoCategoryId matches the one in the SQLite database. However, when the spinner is displayed, the default value (which I add to the `PhotoCategories` property, PhotoCategory = 0, CategoryName="[Choose a Category]") is shown. The only fix I've found is this (which works ok) code added to the View:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PhotoView);
   //If we're in Update mode, select the relevant photo category in the spinner:
   PhotoViewModel photoViewModel = (PhotoViewModel)ViewModel;
   if (photoViewModel.ScreenMode == Constants.ScreenMode.Update) {
      MvxSpinner photoCategorySpinner = FindViewById<MvxSpinner>(Resource.Id.photoCategorySpinner);
      int itemPosition = 0;
      int selectedPhotoCategoryId = photoViewModel.SelectedPhotoCategory.PhotoCategoryId;
      foreach (PhotoCategory photoCategory in photoViewModel.PhotoCategories) {
        if (photoCategory.PhotoCategoryId == selectedPhotoCategoryId) {
            photoCategorySpinner.SetSelection(itemPosition);
        }
    itemPosition++;
   }                
 }
```

I've also tried using the GetPosition method of the MvxSpinner.Adapter but this always returns -1 for PhotoCategoryId, CategoryName or SelectedPhotoCategory as the parameter value.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding

```
  SelectedItem SelectedPhotoCategory
```

should set this for you - and should use `Equals` to find the correct item to select in the spinner.

This certainly seems to work in the very latest code when testing using the SpinnerViewModel in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples

I know there was a bug reported recently on the use of `==` versus `Equals` in one of the bindings - but I don't think this effects the spinner (see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/309).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Stuart. The only obvious difference I can see in you SpinnerViewModel example is that your spinner is bound to a list of strings whereas mine is a `List<PhotoCategory>` where a PhotoCategory has 2 properties: `public int PhotoCategoryId` and `public string CategoryName` each with a get and set. Unfortunately my Xamarin trial licence has just run out a couple of hours ago so I'm relying on our purchasing department to sort a licence out ASAP before I can do any further testing and report back.

Comment: Ask support for an extension - they do supply. Then check your `Equals` implementation in your `PhotoCategory`

Comment: Ah, so I have to provide my own implementation of the `Equals` method. I'll look into that next week and also email Xamarin Support as you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorted! I added `public override bool Equals(object obj)` method to my class which effectively contains `return this.PhotoCategoryId == ((PhotoCategory)obj).PhotoCategoryId;` (with some exception handling) and bingo the binding now works without the need for any code in the View. I've also got a 30 day extension on my Xamarin licence after contacting support as you suggested. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: @Stuart Thanks for this tip, as soon as I implemented Equals, all worked well!